# How to overcome "No repositories found" error in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, nexus

I'm getting "No repository found" errors in IntelliJ not only for our own repository, but even for the majority of the repositories listed by default under Maven configuration. Only jfrog.org and jboss.org are reported OK with artifacts.

The rest of the repositories are online and contain artifacts if accessed with a browser or with Maven from command line.

There's a bug report on JetBrains site: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122332, submitted three months ago.

Is there a workaround?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14):

If the server is Artifactory, you need to add `/api/` to the end of the URL.

Using the example of the standard JFrog one: the URL set in IntelliJ is `http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/api/`. IntelliJ will discover the repositories with a GET request to that URL with `/repositories` appended (`http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/api/repositories`). This should return a JSON array describing the repositories on the server.

I've never used non-Artifactory servers, so I don't know about those.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `/service/local/` helped me with sonatype nexus.